# jquery plugin issue when trying to reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep getting the error when trying to reload a page:
jquery-cycle2.js?v=3.0.43&t=1481602536:608 [cycle2] slideshow must be initialized before sending commands; "goto" ignored

Comment: If you want help with your code, you have to post it.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you are trying to issue the `goto` command for an element that has not yet been initialized to be a cycle2 slideshow.

If this is your element:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg">
</div>
```

And you are trying to execute this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#slideshow').cycle('goto', 2);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ogb4kdwz/)

You will get the error because you have not initialized the `#slideshow` element to be a cycle2 slideshow.

You can fix that by either having it auto-initialized by including the `cycle-slideshow` class on the element:

```
<div id="slideshow" class="cycle-slideshow">
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ogb4kdwz/2/)

Or by programmatically initializing it:

```
$(function() {
  $('#slideshow').cycle(); // Initialize the element to be a slideshow.
  $('#slideshow').cycle('goto', 2);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ogb4kdwz/3/)

---

When asking a question like this, you really should include the relevant HTML and JavaScript that you have written. It is also helpful to include a link to the JQuery plugin you are using: [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/).